# Nachfolgend vs folgend

Tags: idiom, idiomaticity

Im ersten Augenblick scheint es, dass die folgenden Ausdrücke synonym sind, gibt es aber irgendwelche Unterschiede zwischen den beiden?

> (a) In der nachfolgenden Arbeit (...)
>
> (b) In der folgenden Arbeit (...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nachfolgend und folgend sind nur fast Synonyme.

Nachfolgend weist mehr darauf hin, dass etwas "**unmittelbar**" nachfolgt.

"In der folgenden Arbeit" könnte ausserdem auch bedeuten, dass diese Arbeit erst noch folgen wird (also noch gar nicht existiert, aber doch geplant ist). Das könnte nur der Kontext ganz sicher klären.

Nachfolgend: Unmittelbar danach.
Folgend: Irgendwo/irgendwann, aber auf jeden Fall danach/dahinter.

Die feststehende Redewendung "im Folgenden" besagt nur, dass die gesuchte Information weiter hinten im Text/im Buch steht. "Nachfolgend finden Sie noch weitere Informationen" bedeutet dagegen, dass jetzt gleich die Informationen kommen, und nicht erst in dreissig Kapiteln.

As a German native speaker I think that "nachfolgend" and "folgend" are almost synonyms, but not exact ones.

Nachfolgend means more that the next following element is meant.
Folgend means that one of the following elements is meant.

Concerning the original phrases:

> (a) In der nachfolgenden Arbeit (...)

Gemeint ist die unmittelbar nachfolgende Arbeit. Da kann nichts dazwischen sein.

> (b) In der folgenden Arbeit (...)

Meint, dass die Arbeit folgt oder folgen wird. Aber es muss nicht die unmittelbar nächste Arbeit sein.

Answer (score 5):

*nachfolgend* betont stärker, dass das, worum es geht, wirklich im Anschluss folgt. Ich würde *nachfolgend* deshalb zum Beispiel nicht gebrauchen, wenn ich nur eine Fundstelle angebe.

Bei

> *In der nachfolgenden Arbeit wird das Thema Spielsucht diskutiert.*

erwarte ich, dass die Arbeit folgt (etwa als nächster Beitrag in einer Zeitschriftenausgabe). Wenn hingegen bloß eine Fundstelle folgt, also etwa:

> *In der nachfolgenden Arbeit wird das Thema Spielsucht diskutiert:*
>
> - Müller, *Der will doch nur spielen! Zum Suchtpotenzial von Sportwetten in der Zwergschnauzer-Community, Zeitschrift für Hundesoziologie 55(3), 2018, 153.*

ist dies aus meiner Sicht überraschend und stilistisch zumindest suboptimal. Dort sollte man besser auf *folgend* zurückgreifen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich wage die These, dass *nachfolgend* ein Bürokratenausdruck ist und dass das Wort in den meisten Fällen<sup>1</sup> eleganter durch *folgend* ersetzt werden kann. Siehe folgende [sic] Beispiele:

> In folgendem Text finden Sie das Wort *nachfolgend* stets durch *folgend* ersetzt.
>
> In der folgenden Arbeit wird das Thema *bürokratische Manierismen in der deutschen Sprache* in klarem, einfachem Deutsch erörtert.
>
> Zu dieser These trug der Autor verschiedene Argumente vor. Die [darauf] folgende Debatte in den Kommentaren brachte weitere interessante Aspekte zu Tage.

Ich sehe keinen semantischen noch stilistischen Gewinn, hier dem *folgend* ein *nach* anzuhängen. Es ist semantisch ohnedies redundant. Wie sollte Y auf X folgen, wenn nicht *nach*?

Dass es sich bei Textverweisen trotzdem weitgehend durchgesetzt hat, mag mit folgender Überlegung erklärt werden: Manchmal möchte man einem Wort mehr Gewicht geben und verlängert es deswegen durch allerlei Prothesen.

Man sieht dies gut illustriert am

> Nachfolger

Der Nachfolger ist eine Person, die einer anderen Person in einer bestimmten Funktion folgt, zum Beispiel als Betriebsinhaber, Geschäftsführerin, o.ä. Man spricht auch bei Autos vom

> Nachfolgermodell

(und nicht oder nur selten vom Folgemodell, obwohl man das gut tun könnte), und dies wird im allgemeinen nicht als bürokratische Überfrachtung gesehen. Vermutlich weil

> *Folger

einfach zu kurz wäre und man fürchtet, das Wort werde in dieser Kürze dem Ohr des Publikums entgleiten.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Eine Ausnahme nennt Kommentator Philipp, siehe unten.

Comment: Bei deinem Eleganz-Imperativ _»ersetze nachfolgend durch folgend«_ solltest du auch an die akustische Ausgewogenheit denken. Du kannst sicher sein, dass es Sätze gibt, die bei Streichung der Silbe _»nach«_ klanglich verlieren.

Comment: Ein Folger könnte auch das sein, was auf Twitter ein Follower ist und in der Bibel ein Jünger. Dass der passende Begriff klanglich besser sei halte ich dagegen für eine Fehlbeobachtung.

Comment: So ist es - einr typischer Fall von bürokratischer Tautologie. "Folgen" enthält doch schon das "nach", was soll es denn sonst sein. "Vorfolgen"?

Comment: @Pollitzer  Ich stimme insofern zu, als auch der Rhythmus einer sprachlichen Äußerung wichtig sein kann, und dies nicht nur in Versen, sondern durchaus auch in der Prosa.

Comment: @IQV  Da wird dem Verb eine unnötige Vorsilbe *aufoktroyiert*.

Comment: @userunknown   Interessante Beobachtung. In der Tat: Warum hat sich für den *Follower* (Abonnent bestimmter Mitteilungen im Internet), der ja eher mühsam auszusprechen ist, nicht der *Folger* etabliert?

Comment: Wenn du (z. B. in einer Fachzeitschrift) in einem Text auf den Artikel verweist, der als nächstes kommt, verwendest du dann auch *folgend*? *In folgendem Artikel wird näher auf die Problematik des richtigen Gebrauchs der Ausdrücke »folgend« und »nachfolgend« eingegangen.* Wenn dieser Satz in einen längeren Text eingebettet ist, hört sich *folgend* für mich danach an, dass gleich ein Artikel genannt wird, nicht danach, dass der Artikel tatsächlich folgt. Dazu müsste noch ein *auf diesen Artikel folgenden o. ä. ergänzt werden. *Nachfolgend* ist da (zumindest in meinen Ohren) eindeutig.

Comment: @Philipp  Ja, da hast du Recht. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend leicht modifiziert. Danke.

Comment: Ich halte das Präfix *nach* auch in praktisch allen Fällen für verzichtbar,möchte aber einen weiteren Punkt anbringen:  *folgen* _kann_ den zeitliche Ablauf bezeichnen, aber auch Aufforderungen/Anweisungen nachzukommen. Das Präfix schließt die zweite Bedeutung aus.

Comment: @guidot  Ja, wenn man das Verb *folgen* allein auf weiter Flur antrifft, kann man natürlich nicht wissen, ob es zeitlichen Ablauf meint oder Gehorsam. Aber meistens is ja so ein Verb kein Wildpferd sondern in einen Kontext eingespannt.

Answer (score 2):

(a) bezieht sich i. d. R. auf den unmittelbar nachfolgenden Text, leitet z. B. eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit ein.

Auch (b) kann diesen Bezug haben, kann sich aber auch auf eine Arbeit beziehen, die im Folgetext nicht wörtlich wiedergegeben wird:

> In seiner ersten Arbeit hat Professor Wildgruber nicht viel mehr getan
>   als eine Behauptung aufzustellen. In der folgenden Arbeit hat er
>   jedoch den Beweis geliefert.

In diesem Beispiel »nachfolgenden« zu verwenden, wäre natürlich auch nicht falsch. Ich würde die beiden Wörter als Synonyme bezeichnen.

*Beispiele für Formulierungen, die häufiger mit »nachfolgend« anzutreffen sind als mit »folgend«*

> - Das nachfolgend Genannte hebt diesen Aspekt hervor.
> - Die Warnblinkanlage alarmiert nachfolgende Fahrer.
> - Angela Merkel, nachfolgend »Angie« genannt, ...

*Beispiele für Formulierungen, die häufiger mit »folgend« anzutreffen sind als mit »nachfolgend«*

> - Am folgenden Tag räumte er den Keller auf. / In der folgenden Woche wurde es stürmisch und kalt.
> - Dem grünen Wagen folgend erreichte er den Hafen.
> - Folgendes ist zu beachten: Beginne ein Haus nie mit dem Dach.